# why help() command under ipdb gives an error

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, ipdb

In `ipython`  I can issue following command and it gives me help:

```
In [1]: help(["foo", "bar", "baz"])

class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
 |
 |  __contains__(...)
 |      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
...
```

But when I do the same inside `ipdb` I get an error:

```
ipdb> help(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
*** No help on (["foo", "bar", "baz"])
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`help` is a special command in pdb. You'll need to explicitly call `p help(obj)` instead of `help(obj)`. You can see the difference if you just call `help` by itself in pdb.